# Problem with binary decision variable constraints in VRP

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, solver, cplex, linearization, vehicle-routing

I would like to create non-linear violation costs in my VRP. I already created my whole VRP with time windows in which I have these decision variable:

```
dvar float+ w[N][D]; // violation time for late arrivals for every node and every day
```

These dvars are working, but now I want to make a link with the violation costs decision variables, which are:

```
dvar boolean a1[N][D];// no violation 
dvar boolean a2[N][D];// soft violation of 0-5 minutes
dvar boolean a3[N][D];// soft violation of 6-10 minutes
dvar boolean a4[N][D];// soft violation of 11 -15 minutes 
dvar boolean a5[N][D];// soft violation of 15+ minutes
```

I want to force:

```
a1[N][D] to be 1, when w[N][D] <=0, 0 otherwise
a2[N][D] to be 1, when w[N][D] >0 & <=5, 0 otherwise
a3[N][D] to be 1, when w[N][D] >5 & <=10, 0 otherwise
a4[N][D] to be 1, when w[N][D] >10 & <=15, 0 otherwise
a5[N][D] to be 1, when w[N][D] >=16, 0 otherwise
```

Then I have:

```
  forall(i in N, d in D)
  (a1[i][d] + a2[i][d] + a3[i][d] + a4[i][d] + a5[i][d]) == 1;
```

There is still something wrong with these constraints though.

```
forall(i in N, d in D)
  (a1[i][d] + a2[i][d] + a3[i][d] + a4[i][d] + a5[i][d]) == 1; //sum of all a's = 1

forall(i in N, d in D)
  w[n][d]<= (5*a2[i][d]) + 1000*(1-a2[i][d]); // a2 == 1 when w[n][d]>0 & <=5

forall(i in N, d in D)
  (6*a3[i][d] - 1000*(a3[i][d]-1))<= w[i][d]; // a3

forall(i in N, d in D)
   w[i][d] <= (10*a3[i][d]) + 1000*(1-a3[i][d]); // a3

forall(i in N, d in D)
  (11*a4[i][d] - 1000*(a4[i][d]-1))<= w[i][d]; //a4

forall(i in N, d in D)
   w[i][d] <= (15*a4[i][d]) + 1000*(1-a4[i][d]); // a4

forall(i in N, d in D)
  (16*a5[i][d] - 1000*(a5[i][d]-1))<= w[i][d]; //a5
```

it sets a5==1 for all constraints.

Furthermore, w is used in the model as:

```
forall (i in N, d in D:q[i][d]>=1)
y[i][d] - w[i][d] <= sl[i][d]; // late arrival time soft
```

where y[i][d] is the arrival time variable and sl the soft time window

Answer (score 6):

Here's a stronger formulation that uses the same variables and fewer constraints, assuming $L \le w_{i,d} \le U$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^5 a_{k,i,d} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$ and $d$}\\ 
L a_{1,i,d} + 1 a_{2,i,d} + 6 a_{3,i,d} + 11 a_{4,i,d} + 16 a_{5,i,d} 
&\le w_{i,d}
&&\text{for all $i$ and $d$}\\ 
0 a_{1,i,d} + 5 a_{2,i,d} + 10 a_{3,i,d} + 15 a_{4,i,d} + U a_{5,i,d} 
&\ge w_{i,d}
&&\text{for all $i$ and $d$}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

You can impose
$$
a_{nd} + b_{nd} + f_{nd} + g_{nd} =1
$$
And link these variables with $\omega_{nd}$ as follows :

\begin{align*}
 &\omega_{nd} \le 5 a_{nd} +M(1-a_{nd})\\
6 b_{nd} - M(1-b_{nd}) \le & \; \omega_{nd} \le 10 b_{nd} +M(1-b_{nd})\\
11 f_{nd}  - M(1-f_{nd}) \le & \; \omega_{nd} \le 15 f_{nd} +M(1-f_{nd}) \\
 16 g_{nd}  - M(1-g_{nd}) \le & \; \omega_{nd}  \\
\end{align*}

For example, if $\omega_{nd}=1$, only the first constraint will be active with $a_{nd} = 1$.

If $\omega_{nd}=7$, only the second one will be active with $b_{nd} = 1$, and so forth.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I added an extra boolean for the case of w[i][d] == 0. Then I imposed: a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 == 1 (see changed question).

Comment: It is still not working, I wonder what is wrong with the code posted above.

Comment: Can you show what is not working ? (what constraint/cost is not properly enforced for example)

Comment: It sets a1 == 1 for all nodes and all days and it changes my w[i][d] to my big M value (1000)

Comment: Are you sure you have constraints that activate the violation time correctly ? if the violation time takes value $1000$ maybe it is not well defined.

Comment: Let me add the other constraints in the question above as well. Maybe that could help?

Comment: yes indeed, the more (relevant) information, the better chances to get a good answer.

Comment: w[i][d] can be in a range of minumum 0 and 240 maximum

Comment: In your last equation, shouldn't it be $y+w \le s$ ? Since $w \ge 0$, it is activated when $y > s$, so you want $y \le s - w$.

Answer (score 1):

You could use logical constraints instead of big M with hard coded 1000

```
range N=1..2;
range D=1..3;

dvar boolean a1[N][D];
dvar int w[N][D] in -10..10;

subject to
{
// a1[N][D] to be 1, when w[N][D] <=0, 0 otherwise
forall(n in N,d in D) a1[n][d]==(w[n][n] <=0);
}
```